# Use of spoken language

Tags: grammaticality

May I use the word *"Indeed"* instead of the word *"Yeah..."* in the beginning of a sentence? I want to understand if it would express a confirmation and compassion. For example:

> "Indeed, the news is not extremely good"

Comment: If you are in educated company, never use "Yeah". However "indeed" would sound strange. Please ask this sort of question on English Language Learners.